# I am Unable to Parse a JSON in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have My jquery function that is returning me data of the formatt:

```
{"Suggestions":[{"name":"RR Restaurant","category_id":"166","locality":"Gayathri Nagar","listing_info":"listing","random_id":"1ll0f0wJ"},{"name":"Oko Restaurant","category_id":"166","locality":"Kumara Krupa","listing_info":"listing","random_id":"0F7ZGV9p"},{"name":"H2O Restaurant","category_id":"166","locality":"Maratha Halli","listing_info":"listing","random_id":"0JNPOyuP"},{"name":"Taj Restaurant","category_id":"166","locality":"Shivaji Nagar","listing_info":"listing","random_id":"7GeA0Kfq"},{"name":"PSR Restaurant","category_id":"166","locality":"Peenya Industrial Area","listing_info":"listing","random_id":"cRvJCwQ3"},{"name":"ac restaurant","category_id":"166","listing_info":"keyword"},{"name":"Indian Restaurant","category_id":"166","listing_info":"keyword"},{"name":"goan restaurant","category_id":"166","listing_info":"keyword"},{"name":"thai restaurant","category_id":"166","listing_info":"keyword"},{"name":"andhra restaurant","category_id":"166","listing_info":"keyword"}],"ImpressionID":"test"}
```

I wish to parse the same to get multiple variables with The field "Name" and "Random Id" in different js variables

```
$("#what").on("keypress", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: "/AutoComplete.do",
        data: {
            query: 'Pest',
            city: 'Bangalore'
        }, // multiple data sent using ajax
        success: function(data) {
            alert();
        }
    });
});
```

My JSON object seems to be nested with "Suggestions" as the parent. Please help.

Comment: alert(data.Suggestions[0].name);

Comment: But I want this to parse over all the "names" I am getting and make a list of Names and random id. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a property to $.ajax function you be ensure that is json parsing:

```
 dataType: 'json'
```

## EDIT

To iterate above the string you can use for(in) or each() jquery

```
 json = "[{'key':'value'},{'key':'value']";
 for(var i in json) {
     console.log(json[i]); 
     //if you see in console [OBJECT Object] you are
     //in a new object you must to iterate nested of this.
 }
```

Comment: The question definitely uses the word "parse", but I think that the topic is really how to *navigate* the object structure and extract content.

Comment: Ok, maybe it's true. I think that user must to explain it better.

Comment: But I want this to parse over all the "names" I am getting and make a list of Names and random id. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#what").on("keypress", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON", //You need this to be inserted in your ajax call.
        cache: false,
        url: "/AutoComplete.do",
        data: {
            query: 'Pest',
            city: 'Bangalore'
        }, // multiple data sent using ajax
        success: function(data) {
            alert();
        }
    });
});
```

After insert ***dataType*** you can probably do this.

```
console.log(data.Suggestions);
```

Also take a look at the API Doc at below url regardless of dataType.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

The data object you are specifying is what will be sent as the arguments to your success method, if you use the GET method.

```
$("#what).on("keypress", function() {
    $.get("/AutoComplete.do", function(response) {
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
        //data.suggestions = [lots of objects];
        //data.suggestions[0].locality = "Gayathri Nagar"
    });
});
```